# Restore default groups for a Linux Mint user

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, group

Due to a typo a Linux Mint account was assinged to `dialout` group only.
Without the `sudo` group and the `root` password I'm not able to restore the funtionality of the account.

Is there a way to either:

- restore the default groups
- change its own groups (`usermod -aG groups <user>` requires elevated privileges)

Comment: If you don't have sudo or root permissions on this machine, how did you manage to wipe a user's groups and set it to dialout in the first place?

Comment: Using sudo you can mess up your own account. That will lock you out.

Comment: @ExecutionByFork as Lambert said, it was a wrong `sudo usermod` command (missing `a`) to remove all groups.

Answer (score 4):

Try reading `/etc/group-`. This is a backup file which should have the last saved configuration, so if you haven't made changes to user groups multiple times, the old information should be in here.

If you have made other changes after, or the group information you need isn't present, I believe you are out of luck. In this case, recovering the past groups of a user probably isn't possible unless you previously printed that information to the terminal and can scroll up again to find it. As for changing a user's groups without `sudo`, you're out of luck there too. It is not possible to change groups without root permissions, short of an exploit, because that would be a wide open route for privilege escalation. As Lambert suggested in their answer, if you have the ability to boot from a USB on this machine, you can do that to achieve root permissions, and mount the Mint filesystem to edit `/etc/group`.

Group information is stored in `/etc/group`. You can use `ls -la` to show the permissions of this file, and thus find out for sure if there is any way you can write to it. Mine outputs the following:

```
$ ls -la /etc/group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1330 Dec 13 10:26 /etc/group
```

The above shows that only root has write permissions to this file, so only root can edit user groups. You can read about the group file format [here](http://linuxconfig.net/manuals/howto/etc-group-file.html).

Comment: Bottom line: even if I can reading the backup group file I cannot restore it without root permissions. By the way, the user says the root password was set the same of user account but when he tries to login as root, the credentials are refused.

Comment: I interpreted your question on restoring the default groups to a user as you not remembering which groups were assigned, so that's why I mentioned `/etc/group-`. You are right, you will need root permissions to update the groups for a user. If you do not have access to root on your machine, you will have to boot a linux OS from a USB where you do have root permissions, then mount the filesystem that contains the messed up group file to change it.

Comment: As for logging in as root, is this user logging in remotely, like via SSH? If this is the case, remote root login is probably disabled. Does the user have physical access to this machine? Or is it in the cloud somewhere?

Comment: It's a laptop and he's logging in front of the machine.

Comment: Then in that case, he should be able to login to root just fine granted he has the right password. If I had to guess, he is mistaking the `sudo` password for the "root" password. He may think that using `sudo` to run a program as root is the same as using `su` to login as root and then run the program. It is not. If a user is in the sudo group, they use their own password to run programs as root. I'm willing to bet the root password is actually different than the user account.

Comment: That is *exactly* what I told him. But he said he *thinks* both passwords (user and root) were set to the same one. Because the root login is refused, I'm pretty sure he's wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps:

1. Boot from Live media
2. Mount the Mint image from disk
3. Edit/correct `/etc/group`
4. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/219083/default-groups-for-user-in-ubuntu.

To view the default groups (or at least the ones that were assigned to the default user at the very beginning), run:

```
sudo grep user-setup /var/log/installer/syslog
```

---

If one has root access, one can add groups to a user using `usermod -aG`. The following example command would add 7 groups to `user123`.

```
usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,lpadmin,sudo,sambashare,dip,plugdev user123
```

---

If one does not have root access, there's several (questions for that:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user,
https://askubuntu.com/questions/59364/i-accidentally-removed-myself-from-sudoers-how-can-i-fix-this,
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059954/how-to-recover-from-accidentally-removing-the-sudo-group, etc.

To summarize, enter advanced options or recovery mode in the GRUB menu and drop to root shell. There, one would be able to run `usermod -aG` as above.

---

In any case, group changes only take effect after **logging out and logging back in**.